# Button does not deallocate

Tags: ios, iphone, button, swift

```
var ExitImg: UIImage!
var ExitButton: UIButton!

func missileHitAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    self.view.viewWithTag(12221)?.removeFromSuperview()
    ExitImg = nil
    ExitButton = nil
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
ExitImg = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "/Users/Joca/Desktop/Game_dev/missile_gun1")
    ExitButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    ExitButton.frame = CGRectMake(5, 285, 70, 30)
    ExitButton.imageView?.tag = 12221
    ExitButton.setBackgroundImage(ExitImg, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    ExitButton.addTarget(self, action: "missileHitAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(ExitButton)
```

}

This is a sample test project for deallocating buttons, on button press button should be deallocated, but its not :(

Comment: What does "deallocate" mean to you? Why do you think a particular button would "deallocate" and how would you know if it did (or didn't)?

Comment: @matt Perhaps "deallocated" is a poor choice of words (because the more fundamental issue is that it's not being removed from its superview because he's not setting the tag properly).

Comment: Well that's what I'm trying to clarify. He doesn't respond, so it is not at all clear what he's really asking.

Comment: i am still a noob to swift, i made a mistake with tag, but with deallocate i mean to free memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a button, but are not setting its tag. Instead, you are setting its image view's tag. Instead of:

```
ExitButton.imageView?.tag = 12221
```

I think you intended:

```
ExitButton.tag = 12221
```

Comment: BTW, Josip, why are you even using `tag` if you're assigning the button to some variable? Wouldn't `ExitButton.removeFromSuperview()` be simpler? Why keep track of both instance variables and `tag` values? Certainly, feel free to do whatever you want, but it seemed curious to me...